# Access 2010 Subform not loading for one user

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Recently, my team's Microsoft Access databases have been migrated from Access 2003 to 2010. Obviously that causes a many problems, but we got most of them figured out. There is one problem, however, that I can't seem to fix.

Many people use this Access application with no issues at all, but about three of my users are experiencing a peculiar problem.

There is a subform within a form and its contents get loaded through a query. There is a box for a picture, a text box, a check box, and a button on this subform. For myself and 99% of the people using the application, the picture loads and everything appears as it should. For the 3 people experiencing the problem, however, the entire subform is completely blank.

The data is stored in OLE Objects and everybody is using the same data.

I can't figure out why it would work for so many people but fail for others. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Are the three users running a version of access older than 2007? I recall a problem in which users could run the newer database fine until they encountered an attachment field or any of the new features. Run through this list http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cc907897.aspx and see if anything jumps out at you. It gives some examples of problems, what causes them, and solutions to make your database backward compatible (if that IS your problem).

Comment: All users are using Access 2010. I even re-installed all of Office 2010 on the user's computer and the problem persists.

Comment: Well, there goes my suggestion :). Maybe add some code in the parent form's load event to refresh and/or requery the subform to see if that makes it appear?

Comment: The only problem with this suggestion is that everyone is using the same code, so I don't understand why it would work for somebody and not for somebody else. It makes me think it has something to do with either security/permissions, or some type of settings outside of Access.

Comment: Did you ensure to "Enable Content" and make the file a trusted document? Sometimes when you force a form on open of the database, the dialogs become obscured and users forget to 'enable content'. This has resulted in unusual behavior in some of my databases.